# After installing Ubuntu alongside Windows, Windows boots fine and I can log in but Windows can't find data

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 I used the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/343370/527764) to [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352#343352)

Firstly I chose something else, secondly made a partition from my hard disk. If I remember correctly, I used Gparted to make a new partition from an empty part of my disk. The installation was successful.

Furthermore, when I boot Windows it works too. I can log into my account in Windows.

However, I get an error message saying

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop is unavailable...

Also, I cannot find my data. I cannot even find "this pc" or C drive. Or anything. It seems I've lost my data. But I don't think I deleted it, I think Windows just cannot find the partition.

How can I get my data back?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Preinstall Windows is UEFI. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I guess BIOS. I have applied instructions said below. Now I have got access to my data. I have found everything. But I do not have any of the settings I made before. It seems I have to set my account again, ie the language of the keyboard or activate my matlab license again and stuff like that.. Neither I can use the search or other built in functions  if I want to find anything. I have to use the command window everytime I want to do something like that. Is it possible to fix this somehow or should I configure everything again and get used to this bugs? Could I avoid to install Windows again?

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand your question. I have bought this HP laptop with installed Windows 10 on it, and now I have installed ubuntu successfully alongside win10  using lili and booting from a pendrive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Windows File Explorer.
2. On the *View* ribbon, put a check in the checkbox marked *Hidden items*.
3. Right-click and copy the Desktop folder contained in the Default folder - `C:\users\Default\`
4. Browse to: `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile`
5. Right-click and paste the Desktop folder into the systemprofile folder.
6. Reboot (not shutdown) the computer.

Comment: Thank you, it has worked, so I found my data. But all settings and personalisation lost. Can I fix it on an elegant way or should I apply every settings again manually? I also get the same error massage if I want to search after anything on my Windows. Only the use of command window works for this. Do you have any idea how to fix this "bug"?

Comment: @Neuralguy 1. Back up your Windows data now so you don't "lose" it again. 2. Apply settings manually if you can't find a better solution. 3. How to regain full use of the Windows desktop graphical interface instead of cmd.exe is a Windows question that should be asked as a separate question on [Super User Q&A](https://superuser.com/), not on Ask Ubuntu. 4. There is probably something quick and easy to do that will get full use of your Windows desktop back. You just need to ask about it at the right website.